# elasticsearch - Return term frequency of a single field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have being trying to use facet to get the term frequency of a field. My query returns just one hit, so I would like to have the facet return the terms that have the most frequency in a particular field.

My mapping:

```
{
"mappings":{
    "document":{
        "properties":{
            "tags":{
                "type":"object",
                "properties":{
                    "title":{
                        "fields":{
                            "partial":{
                                "search_analyzer":"main",
                                "index_analyzer":"partial",
                                "type":"string",
                                "index" : "analyzed"
                            }
                            "title":{
                                "type":"string",
                                "analyzer":"main",
                                "index" : "analyzed"
                            }
                        },
                        "type":"multi_field"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},

"settings":{
    "analysis":{
        "filter":{
            "name_ngrams":{
                "side":"front",
                "max_gram":50,
                "min_gram":2,
                "type":"edgeNGram"
            }
        },

        "analyzer":{
            "main":{
                "filter": ["standard", "lowercase", "asciifolding"],
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "partial":{
                "filter":["standard","lowercase","asciifolding","name_ngrams"],
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Test data:

```
 curl -XPUT localhost:9200/testindex/document -d '{"tags": {"title": "people also kill people"}}'
```

Query:

```
 curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/testindex/document/_search?pretty=1' -d '
{
    "query":
    {
       "term": { "tags.title": "people" }
    },
    "facets": {
       "popular_tags": { "terms": {"field": "tags.title"}}
    }
}'
```

This result

```
"hits" : {
   "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.99381393,
    "hits" : [ {
    "_index" : "testindex",
    "_type" : "document",
    "_id" : "uI5k0wggR9KAvG9o7S7L2g",
    "_score" : 0.99381393, "_source" : {"tags": {"title": "people also kill people"}}
 } ]
},
"facets" : {
  "popular_tags" : {
  "_type" : "terms",
  "missing" : 0,
  "total" : 3,
  "other" : 0,
  "terms" : [ {
    "term" : "people",
    "count" : 1            // I expect this to be 2
   }, {
    "term" : "kill",
    "count" : 1
  }, {
    "term" : "also",
    "count" : 1
  } ]
}
```

}

The above result is not what I want. I want to have the frequency count be 2

```
"hits" : {
   "total" : 1,
   "max_score" : 0.99381393,
   "hits" : [ {
   "_index" : "testindex",
   "_type" : "document",
   "_id" : "uI5k0wggR9KAvG9o7S7L2g",
   "_score" : 0.99381393, "_source" : {"tags": {"title": "people also kill people"}}
} ]
},
"facets" : {
"popular_tags" : {
  "_type" : "terms",
  "missing" : 0,
  "total" : 3,
  "other" : 0,
  "terms" : [ {
    "term" : "people",
    "count" : 2            
  }, {
    "term" : "kill",
    "count" : 1
  }, {
    "term" : "also",
    "count" : 1
  } ]
 }
}
```

How do I achieve this? Is facet the wrong way to go?

Comment: May I know if my answer helped?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A facet counts the documents, not the terms belonging to them. You get 1 because only one document contains that term, it doesn't matter how many times that happens. I'm not aware of an out of the box way to return the term frequency, the facet is not a good choice.
That information could be stored in the index if you enable the term vectors, but there's no way to read the term vectors from elasticsearch by now.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using facets?

Comment: There is in 1.0 (beta2 available) as term_vectors got exposed (but you do need to store term_vectors): http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-termvectors.html .

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately term frequency for field is not available in Elastic. GitHub project [Index TermList](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-index-termlist) is working with Lucene's Terms and calculate  total number of occurrences of all docs, you can check it and alternate for your needs.