# How can I query/filter an exact count by an array of values in Elasticsearch?

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, facet

I have these documents:

```
{"title": "aa","cast": ["a","b","c","a"]}
{"title": "bb","cast": ["a","b","c","b"]}
{"title": "cc","cast": ["a","b","c","c"]}
```

I get the result using the faceting.

```
facets": {
      "cast_result": {
         "_type": "terms",
         "missing": 0,
         "total": 9,
         "other": 0,
         "terms": [
            {
               "term": "c",
               "count": 3
            },
            {
               "term": "b",
               "count": 3
            },
            {
               "term": "a",
               "count": 3
            }
         ]
      }
  }
}
```

but I want the result that the count of "a" is four,Because the frequency of "a" is four in the real document."b" and "c" also like the "a".

Comment: Can you post the full query of this ? Also the analyzer applied for "cast"

Comment: The cast uses the standard analyzer.
The query code:
POST /index_test/_search?search_type=count
{
    
   "facets": {
      "cast_result": {
          "terms": {
             "field": "cast"
          }
         
      }
   }
}

Comment: Seem that it try to return count of document rather than the term frequency itself. I'm trying some other methods to see if it help

Comment: Looking forward to your good news.

Comment: This links may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217849/elasticsearch-return-term-frequency-of-a-single-field, https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-index-termlist

Answer (score 0):

[image: create the index]

[image: query]

[image: the sum of term is the answer]

But I find a question ,when the number of the shards is more than 2, the answer is wrong ,so it must be lower than 2.It doesn't matter about the number of replicas.

Comment: the sum of term is the answer.